# Angular6 Date time check with ngIf inside html template

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

I am using `Angular6`.

Below is the `ngfor` with div. Here the api outputs the meeting date and time with status. Normally the status is upcoming.

If the date time is 09/18/2018. and Time is 5.30 Pm.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let todayinfo of todaylist  |  paginate: { id: 'todaypage', itemsPerPage: itemperpage, currentPage: page, totalItems: todaytotal}">

<div class="meeting-date-time" title="Date Time" >
              {{todayinfo.meeting_date  | date: 'MMM d, y '}} <br>{{todayinfo.displayTime}}               
              </div>
<div>{{todayinfo.status}} </div>

</div>
```

The upcoming status should be changed as `Join`, before 15 minutes of the meeting time.

i.e at Sep 18 at  5.15pm the content need to change as `Join`. Here how to check the date time check condition. It is displayed inside the loop. If there is any click action we will check this with separate function. Without any events how to check the date time condition here?

Now the Output is

```
Sep 18 2018 5.30 PM   --- Upcoming 
Sep 4 2018  9.00 AM -- Completed
Spe 17 2018 7.15 PM -- Upcoming
```

These `upcoming` need to change to `Join` before 15 min of the corresponding date time.

Comment: Initially, you can check that when user enter the site and list is displayed then set up maybe every minute simple check for time and update status.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple solution how you can achieve that:

```
const meetings = [
    {meeting_date: new Date(2018, 8, 17, 11, 44), status: null},
    {meeting_date: new Date(2018, 8, 17, 12, 45), status: null}
];
const today = new Date();

meetings.filter(meeting => (meeting.meeting_date.getTime() - today.getTime()) <= 900000).forEach(meeting => meeting.status = 'Join');
```

It will check for meeting where time difference is less or equal to 900000(15min) and mark their status as 'Join'.